# How to get properties defined outside of module.export from require object

Tags: node.js

I am struggling to get const properties define outside of module.exports from the object where I am using that module. here is simple example:

**ServiceX.js**

```
const _ = require('lodash');
module.exports = {
  testFirstName: function () {
    console.log('Nodics');
  }
}
```

**ServiceY.js**

```
const utils = require('utils');
module.exports = {
  testLastName: function () {
    console.log('framework');
  }
}
```

now if I import both file via require and merging via _.merge(). Output file contain both of the methods, but it doesn't contain any of the const variable define outside exports.

```
let combined = _.merge(require('ServiceX'), require('ServiceY'));
```

writing this combined to the third file some this MyService

even if I print this combined object via `console.log(combined)`, I get only both functions, not const properties.

Use case I have:
I have n-number of files in different location, I need to read files, merge all and create a new file with merged content.

Please help me,

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to create a new file with merged content? The way you're doing it now should work well?

Answer (score 0):

A problem here is that a service currently looks like:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
module.exports = {
  testFirstName: function () {
    console.log('Nodics');
  }
}
```

And the reason for that is that *if* you read all files and concatenate the result then `module.exports` will be overwritten by the last read file.

But if it instead looked like:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
module.exports.testFirstname = function () {
  console.log('Nodics');
}
```

You could pull it off by doing `fs.readFileSync()` on all your services and concatenate the result.

You could also do it as a build command, rather than in code:

`cat service*.js > combined.js`

You will most likely run into other problems, since if one service uses `const _ = require('lodash')` and another is doing the same you will try to redefine a const variable.

To get around this you could move have to move your requires into another scope, so they don't conflict at file level scope.